# CKeditor rich text editor displaying html tags in browser

Tags: html, encoding, ckeditor

I've just installed CKeditor rich text WYSIWYG editor on a site I'm building and it seems to be working ok except for the fact that it inserts text into my mysql database as encoded html rather than regular html and then when the browser outputs this text it converts the encoded data into regular html that then displays in the browser showing the html tags and none of the styling!?

eg I type:

```
"This is text"
```

into the editor and it then inserts

```
&lt;p&gt;This is text&lt;/p&gt;
```

into the database. Then when the page is called the browser converts the above and outouts the following on the page:

```
<p>This is text</p>
```

obviously I just want `"This is text"` to display on the page.

Does anyone know why this is happening/how to solve it please?

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Cheers

Comment: what server side technology you use ? How do you save the contents in the DB? And how are you retrieving them from the DB and showing on the page ?

Comment: my problem was in the method of setting text. if you are looking for a solution try this `CKEDITOR.instances['urId'].setData(rawText)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want CKEditor to create paragraphs for you, set [`config.autoParagraph`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-autoParagraph) to false. Additionally you may want to change enter key behaviour with [`config.enterMode`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-enterMode) set to `CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR`.

And [regarding disappearing styles](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter)...

---

EDIT: OK, it seems I missed your point.

So your website is displaying HTML markup instead of HTML while rendering out what you typed? 
Then the problem is your server side rather than CKEditor. You can verify in your console that `CKEDITOR.instances.yourInstance.getData()` yields the correct, unescaped HTML:

```
<p>This is text</p> // Right!
```

If it is so, and I strongly believe it is, CKEditor's just fine and this is your server app that is converting special chars into entities (i.e. like PHP [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)) while saving to database. You didn't mention what kind of framework/language you use there, so I can just tell you that it is to secure user input to prevent cross-site scripting, breaking layouts etc. and all popular frameworks allow you to disable that feature for a particular field. Simply refer to documentation.

Comment: It's not that it's making paragraphs it's that the html tags are displaying once the page is rendered in the browser. I want the paragraph just don't want the tags to show!

Comment: Ahha, sounds sensible. I'm using PHP with PHPmyadmin and mysql along with CKeditor and whatever software my web host uses to host the site itself. So I guess I'll get in touch with my host and ask a few questions and see if I can get this resolved. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

Modern templating languages tend to autoescape html input.  For example, in DTL it would be displayed correctly in the template by simply using 
{{ object.field_name|safe }}
This is a desired action, since user input is considered untrusted and may be considered malicious.

Answer (score 1):

The browser is not parsing HTML, so on the page displaying (or in the php file) try using `{!  !}` instead of `{{  }}`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using laravel, then you should use `{!! $variable !!}`.

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel 7, 8, and 9 - foreaxample if there is a varable called- $student

and student varable holds "This is Text" in paragraph you must call the varable using singla culy brace front and back, inside two

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).