# CKeditor displaying HTML tags in browser

Tags: php, html, tags, ckeditor, flat-file

I have been searching for a possible cause of this issue but I couldn't find it.

I already saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197011/ckeditor-rich-text-editor-displaying-html-tags-in-browser) topic here but it didn't help me.

I am building a very simple CMS using exactly [this technology](http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1155), plus CKeditor. Everything works just fine until I decide to add some styling on my RTE, like for instance, Bold text. When I press the Submit button, the rendered html has the [b] tags.

After some investigation I went to CKeditor's config file and wrote this: `config.htmlEncodeOutput = false`, which didn't help either.

What might the problem might be? To not leave any questions about my code, I leave you the code below:

A PHP file with all the editable fields that the back end picks up:

```
$text13 = "innehall/text13.txt";
if (isset($_POST['body13'])) {
    $newData = nl2br(htmlspecialchars ($_POST['body13']));
    $handle = fopen($text13, "w");
    fwrite($handle, $newData);
    fclose($handle);
}
if (file_exists($text13)) {

    $myData13 = file_get_contents($text13);
    $myData13 = $myData13;
}
```

The back end file:

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post">
        <label>Beskrivning:</label>
        <textarea class="ckeditor" name="body13" id="body13">
        <?php echo str_replace("<br />","",$myData13); ?>
        </textarea><br>
        <input id="submit" name="myBtn" type="submit" value="Uppdatera fältet" />
</form>
```

A php file with all the sources that the index will pick up:

```
$text13 = "administration/innehall/text13.txt";
if (file_exists($text13)) {

    $myData13 = file_get_contents($text13);
}
```

The index.php

```
<div class="six columns">
      <p><?php echo $myData13 ?></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the contents of the text file you are saving to - I think you will find that the  tags are being escaped but want to check that first.

If the  tags are being escaped when you save then you need to unescape them when you show the output not just echo.

Also I guess $myData15 is meant to be $myData13???

Comment: I~m sorry, the variable is corrected, I copied the wrong code. The contents of the text file? A simple "Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet prosciutto shoulder pork chop brisket salami meatball, biltong strip steak capicola doner spare ribs ham. Brisket short loin flank tongue short ribs, tenderloin chuck pig t-bone kielbasa frankfurter turkey doner corned beef."... Do you mean I would have to write <p><?php echo (htmlspecialchars ($myData13)); ?></p>?

Comment: "If the tags are being escaped when you save then you need to unescape them when you show the output not just echo." - How would I do that?

Comment: Specifically in the text file I am looking for your <b>fdjk</b> tags - can you make some text bold and then just show the raw file data (that is open the file directly using ftp / file manager and see what goes into the text file) my guess is when you are saving using nl2br(specialchar  -> you are escaping the <b> tags - meaning that they will actually render on the page. Check the contents of the file!

Comment: Ok, I took the text above and made it bold. The result is the same both on the txt file and on the rendered html: [b]Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet prosciutto shoulder pork chop brisket salami meatball, biltong strip steak capicola doner spare ribs ham. Brisket short loin flank tongue short ribs, tenderloin chuck pig t-bone kielbasa frankfurter turkey doner corned beef.[/b]

Should I remove the nl2br(specialchar?

Comment: And if I try to make a link, the result is this: [url=http://google.com]Leberkas[/url] - both on the rendered html and on the txt file...

Comment: ok your editor is outputting bb code - find config.js in ckeditor and remove  extraPlugins : 'bbcode' - this should fix it

Comment: It worked! But it created another issue: it was outputting the HTML code. So, I went to the PHP code shown above and I took off the "(htmlspecialchars". It solved the problem but it created me another one: Rendered HTML loses it's properties specified in the HTML. For instance, if I have a <h2><?php echo $myData13 ?></h2>, but in the RTE back end the text is in "paragraph" style, then the RTE will render it as <p> and not as <h2>. It's a minor problem because I can convert it to "Header 2" style at the RTE, but this has never happened before... Still, truly thankful for your help! Cheers! :)