# Text with tags in ckeditor

Tags: php

I have ckeditor in my site, and evertything appears fine when you write something, but when you view it - it shows your post with all the tags, for example:

You write:
**Hello!**

and it actually shows you after you submit it:
< p>< strong>Hello!< /strong>< /p>

(without the spaces)

Any idea what could be the problem?
Thanks alot.

Comment: How are you printing it out after you submit it?

Comment: Question has been asked before. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197011/ckeditor-rich-text-editor-displaying-html-tags-in-browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197011/ckeditor-rich-text-editor-displaying-html-tags-in-browser)

Comment: I'll check that out. Thanks!

Comment: Looked there, didn't help. I am printing it using print, in the PHP.

Comment: Show us your actual code where you're saving the CKEditor text as well as your actual code where you're fetching and printing the CKEditor text. We only want to see the minimum amount of code.

Comment: h2ooooooo, can I get your email address or something so you will be able to help me better?

Comment: @Tom That would ruin the purpose of StackOverflow which is to make sure that the information you get everyone can use by Googling (that's how you found StackOverflow in the first place, was it not?). Edit your post and include the following: 4-5 lines where you save the text in PHP and 4-5 lines where you're printing the text in PHP. Most likely you're using `htmlentities` or a similar function to encode your HTML even though you shouldn't. BTW, to tag a user so they see your answer quicker, use `@username`.

Comment: @h2ooooooo oh, thanks! I'll shortly do it.